# Xpages : How to get all members from a group in java (using ODA) and get their common name

Tags: xpages

I thought I was pretty clever writing this method to load up members of a group. But the values that are returned are not in common name format:

[image]

How can I easily grab these values in common name or easily transform them to common name?

```
private void loadNetworkTeam() {

        try {
            Session session = Factory.getSession();
            Database tmpDB = session.getCurrentDatabase();
            Database tmpDB2 = session.getDatabase(tmpDB.getServer(), "names.nsf");
            View grpView = tmpDB2.getView("($VIMGroups)");

            Vector<Object> nTeam = new Vector<Object>();
            nTeam.addElement("NetWorkTeam");    
            Document grpDoc = grpView.getFirstDocumentByKey("Network Team");
            Item itm = grpDoc.getFirstItem("members");          
            networkTeam.addAll(itm.getValues());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have the ODA available to you I don't think there's ever a need to then use a Vector object.  I would suggest avoiding that like the plague.  Use Lists, Maps and Sets.

Comment: David, don't hurt the Vector's feelings! They are collections too ;-) -> and they never jumble their sequence

Comment: Why the dislike of Vectors, and why the defense. I cannot take a position unless I know more about the debate :).

Answer (score 6):

Use class [Name](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESNAME_CLASS_JAVA.html?lang=en) and its method [getCommon()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COMMON_PROPERTY_JAVA.html?lang=en) to convert a hierarchical name into a common name.

Example:

```java
Item itm = grpDoc.getFirstItem("members");   
List<String> networkTeam =  new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (Object value : itm.getValues()) {
    networkTeam.add(session.createName((String) value).getCommon());
}
```